# Drupal 8 paragraph access in views-view twig file

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

1.) I have added a paragrah with multiple field in my node form

2.) Now i have created a View and added the paragraph field and selected the Formatter as Rendered Entity

3.) In the preview section i can see all my paragraph data , as my twig debug is on i can see file suggestions where i can override the paragraph file

4.) But i want to access my paragraphs fields inside the views-view--unformatted-{{ view_machine_name }}.html.twig file

5.) I access the normal fields inside my content type using

```
view.field.{{ machine_name }}.getvalue(view.result[0])
```

6.) I can access the paragraph complete section by

```
view.field.{{ paragraph_machine_name }}.original_value
```

How can i access the fields inside the paragraph in this view file

Answer (score 2):

This is how i solved this ..

--> I added a relationship of the paragraph field and made it as required

--> After that i selected the relationship in the filter criteria section

--> And then i was able to select all the paragraph fields while adding a new field in the view

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Yes, great answer, the views templates are only good for theming, the heavy stuff has to be configured in the views ui.